# Rails 4 Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html and form_for remote: true not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

**In rails 4 form_for remote: true not working**

and I'm also getting this error in browser console **Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html**

response is expected in js but server is sending back in html format. So instead of **js.erb** file execution it displayed the js code written it

What I already have:

**In application.js** already included

jquery

jquery_ujs

**In application.html.erb** already included

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

**In xyz.js.erb**

```
$('#preview-main').html("<%= escape_javascript( render ('preview'), background_image: @image.image.url ) %>");
```

Note: 'preview' is partial in same view folder

**In controller**

```
def create
    @image = Image.new(image_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @image.save
        format.js { render 'steps/xyz' }
      else
        format.js { render js: 'what is wrong with this :@' }
      end
    end
end
```

**My form**

```
<%= form_for(@image, format: :js, authenticity_token: true, remote: true,:html => {multipart: true, :class => "form-horizontal", :"content-type" => "application/javascript", :'data-type' => 'js'  }) do |f| %>
```

So guide me what is wrong with this thing

Answer (score 0):

**Q: Why remote: true not working in form_for?**

As I was using  `multipart: true` but Images can't be created by ajax form by default. I've to include [jquery.remotipart](http://rubygems.org/gems/remotipart) gem. [How to embed gem in rails app](http://os.alfajango.com/remotipart/).

**My Form:**

```
<%= form_for(@image, format: :js, remote: true,:html => { class: "form-horizontal", multipart: true }) do |f| %>
```

**Remember to add** `//= require jquery.remotipart` ***immidiately after*** `//= require jquery_ujs` in  app/assests/javascripts/application.js  file

**Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html** this was just warning don't effect any thing.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, but my form is no multipart. Any other solutions to this?